# string function workout in php

Tags: php, string, function

I have the string like this,

```
$inp1 = "3 doses at 0[0,0], 1-2 and 6 Month[6,1] [3,2])";
```

in this internally, going to take the values of square bracket.  How can i take this values in the square bracket? any function is there to return the string like this

`[0,0] [6,1] [3,2]`

Thanks in advance for help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
preg_match_all('/\[\d+,\d+\]/', $inp1, $matches);
$result = implode(' ', $matches[0]);
```

Answer (score 1):

you could try with the preg_replace function using a regular expression :

```
$s = "3 doses at 0[0,0], 1-2 and 6 Month[6,1] [3,2])";
$s = preg_replace("/[^\[]*(\[[^\]]*\])[^\[]*/","$1",$s);
echo $s;
```

This outputs

```
[0,0][6,1][3,2]
```